# Does this inequality hold for all n>=1?

Tags: inequality

$$\ln ( \ln ( ( n+1 ) ^ {1/2} ) ) - \ln ( \ln (  n  ^ {1/2} ) ) < \frac1 { (n / \ln (n ) ) ^ 2 
+ 1}$$

It seems that this is true for all $n\geq1$. I tried proving that by induction but I couldn't.

Comment: Please use LaTeX for easy reading.

Comment: What does Ln mean?

Comment: @ Joao :if y=e^x then x=Ln y

Answer (score 0):

$((2/\ln(2))^2+1)^{-1} < (\ln(\ln((2+1)^{1/2}))−\ln(\ln(2^{1/2})))$

Answer (score 0):

So we want to prove that:

$$ \log\left(\log(n+1)\right)-\log\left(\log(n)\right)<\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)^2}\tag{1}$$
where the mean value theorem gives that the LHS of $(1)$ is $\frac{1}{(n+\theta)\log(n+\theta)}$ for some $\theta\in(0,1)$.

Since $ \frac{\log n}{n}\color{red}{>}\frac{1}{n^2+\log^2 n} $ for any $n$ big enough, $(1)$ may hold only in a finite number of cases.

Comment: yes, $7 \le n \le 94$